# How to use contract-out in Racket

Tags: racket, contract, prng

I have written a complimentary-multiply-with-carry PRNG in Racket. I want to use [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html) to restrict access only to certain functions within my library, and [to impose contracts on them](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Function_Contracts.html). Using the Racket Documentation (linked above), I have put the following code at the top of my file to that end:

```
(require data/queue)
(provide 
 (contract-out
  (make-cmwc-gen (-> (listof integer?) integer? integer? integer? procedure?))
  (make-default-cmwc-gen (-> integer? procedure?))
  (make-cmwc-gen-raw (-> queue? integer? integer? integer? procedure?))
  (init-cmwc-seed (-> integer? queue?))))
```

But when I run the file in DrRacket, I get the following error:

```
. contract-out: not a provide sub-form in: (contract-out (make-cmwc-gen (-> (listof 
integer?) integer? integer? integer? procedure?)) (make-default-cmwc-gen (-> integer?   
procedure?)) (make-cmwc-gen-raw (-> queue? integer? integer? integer? procedure?)) 
(init-cmwc-seed (-> integer? queue?)))
```

The code throws no errors and otherwise works when run in DrRacket without the above code inserted.

**What is the proper way to restrict access only to certain functions outside of a source file as well as enforcing their contracts in Racket?**

Comment: Which version of Racket are you using? `contract-out` was added in September, so if you're using it in a version older than 5.2 it won't work. Also, if you can't upgrade for some reason try using `provide/contract`.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I copied a sample program from the racket docs and it didn't work. Further, my version is 5.1.3 . I know that contracts have been enforced prior to 5.2, though. How were they enforced in 5.1.3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*`contract-out`* is new, and introduced in Racket 5.2.  If you're using Racket < 5.2, you can still use [*`provide/contract`*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Attaching_Contracts_to_Values.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/contract/private/provide..rkt%29._provide/contract%29%29):

Example:

```
#lang racket
(provide/contract [f (-> number? number?)])

(define (f x) 42)
```

In Racket 5.2, `contract-out` is preferred because the elements in the contract can be defined after the contract.  That is, if you try something like this in the old system,

```
#lang racket
;; The following will fail since the contract definition doesn't know
;; about p? at the point of its definition.
(provide/contract [f (-> p? p?)])

(define p? number?)
(define (f x) 42)
```

then it'd fail, because `p?` is defined after the contract.

In contrast, `contract-out` works without needing to rearrange definitions:

```
#lang racket
(provide (contract-out [f (-> p? p?)]))

(define p? number?)
(define (f x) 42)
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the differences between provide/contract and contract-out.